# Front end Electron + React JS <-> Backend C++ communication

Tags: c++, reactjs, qt, electron

The program I have is a C++ program that has Qt GUI. The issue with Qt is that it looks really horrible. We are trying to move away from Qt to Electron + ReactJS.

However, our C++ program is "integrated" with the Qt GUI in the sense our Qt GUI is in CPP and part of our program, this means it has direct access to our program APIs.

We have limited RPC capability to allow JSON requests so most of the stuff we can migrate to RPC based. However, there are some features that have to be invoked via C++ class member class methods(public). is there a way for React JS to call into the C++ program?

Comment: Are you aware of node addons? https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: Also are you aware of QT webview? Given your C++ knowhow this seams to be a better solution for your usecase http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html

Comment: @pergy will nodejs addon work with react js? or am I forced to use nodejs

Comment: @HansKoch no I am not aware of QT webview. my current application uses QT on Linux Windows and Mac, how does QT webview play into this?

Comment: @user2584960 In the c++ addon scenario your React will communicate with your main process, which will communicate with the c++ code via addon wrapper. May be an overkill for you but that's the usual way of using c++ code from an electron/nodejs app.

Comment: @pergy "which will communicate with the c++ code via addon wrapper" can you elaborate on this? this is exactly what I need I think. however, how does the c++ addon know how to call into my c++ code? do i need to modify my program?

Comment: @user2584960 read up the link for details (also there are lot of great articles and examples in this topic on the net). Basically you have to provide a wrapper interface for your c++ code, so you'll be able call those functions you provided from JS. Your original code doesn't have to be changed but should be callable from the wrapper interface